# Can we use the preposition "for" with the verb "scoot"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions

I checked the dictionary and found that I can use 'scoot' with 'off' or 'over' but can I use it with 'for'?

Example:

> Kalya got out of bed and scooted for the toilet

Comment: Hi Faith. Please ask one question at a time. It is off-topic to ask completely different questions in one post. I deleted your second question, you can ask as a separate post. Please include the research you have done also.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22and%20scooted%20for%20the%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: The dictionaries I've checked are Longman and Oxford. Thanks.

Comment: @Faith Please include your research _in the question itself_, not as a comment. Comments are ephemeral and may be deleted at any point; the question should still have all the information necessary.

Comment: It's not unknown, but this internet example "... [s]o he hunged him once but he come to life and scooted for the barn ..." gives an idea of the register that may well be involved.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

'To scoot' is a verb for movement and, as such, can use the preposition 'for' when there's a destination (a specific goal) involved. It's not something I would normally say, but I can imagine situations where it would be rather appropriate. For example, if Kayla were to ride a scooter from bed to the toilet (either a recreational scooter or a motorized chair for the disabled), she could aptly be described as scooting for the toilet.

Comment: Your authority to back the claim '[one] can [always] use the preposition 'for' [after a verb of movement] when there's a destination involved'? I'd say these aren't acceptable: He crawled / bounced / drifted / floated / glided / ambled / meandered / traipsed / travelled / ... for the door/bridge/house. The prepositions _to_ or _towards_ are needed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right; there are some in that list I wouldn't use with 'for' in any situation. The 'for' designates the goal of the movement, so - for example - 'wandering' would be a difficult verb, if only due to the implied lack of a goal. If I imagine a baby whose only means of locomotion is crawling, I can imagine him 'crawling for' his mother's cell phone, for example. 'Crawling towards' isn't as satisfying. Is it only my American preference?

Comment: Ah; I'm assuming AHDEL [sense](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/destination) (1a) below for **destination** 1. The place to which one is going ... You seem to be using Collins sense (1): 1. the predetermined end of a journey or voyage. Implying (strict maths sense) intention. // 'For' doesn't necessarily imply _intended_ end ('heading for disaster'). // I personally would use 'crawling for' with neither any locational nor most intended goal endpoints; 'crawling determinedly towards' sounds right to my (UK) ears. Though admittedly 'crawling for the safety of ...' sounds far more acceptable.

Comment: I see how my wording could have been better (and edited the answer for clarity). For me, toward has a connotation of 'in the general direction of', while 'for' has that direction as well as a sense of purpose. Some of the other verbs you mentioned I can imagine being used ironically. "The stick, despising the game of fetch after having been thrown into the river yet again, /drifted/ desperately /for/ the dam in what would prove to be a futile attempt to scorn its captors." It adds a personification that I'm quite fond of (but then, I'm the dry sarcastic type).

Comment: Yes; it's dictatorial to pronounce even quirky usages 'incorrect'. But 'The stick ... drifted desperately for the dam' is hardly a mainstream usage (I'm the dire pun type).

Answer (score 0):

If your meaning is that Kayla was in a hurry to get to the toilet by walking quickly, or that this was the only reason she got out of bed, "scoot" would not be used.  "For" could be used in this way: "Kayla got out of bed and headed for the toilet," which implies that she went directly there.  A colloquial verb that sounds as though it may be related to "scoot" is "skitter," which would be used with "to":  "Kayla got out of bed and skittered to the toilet."  The imagery it conveys is moving very rapidly, like a bug might if you turned on the light, and it would be a humorous use of the verb.  As an aside, "toilet" in the US refers to the fixture inside a restroom or bathroom, a "commode." To use it in referring to the room itself would be considered vulgar.  Further, either "bathroom" or "restroom" is correct to use in a person's residence.  "Restroom" is always used in a public place, since it is not likely an actual bathtub or shower would be found inside.

Source for "skitter":  Merriam Webster online dictionary

Comment: We don't know where the OP is, and *toilet* would be perfectly reasonable in many varieties of English. *Scoot* to me implies something more targeted than skitter which also suggests rapid footsteps as well as rapid movement.

Comment: In which country do people refer to the facilities in their own home as the "restroom"?

Answer (score 0):

Scoot would be a perfectly ordinary verb to use when referring to moving across an object while seated, such as a couch or a chair, e.g.,

> As the movie began, she scooted closer to her boyfriend.

Though your usage is legitimate, it feels more unusual when referring to walking or otherwise moving somewhere. It would actually sound far more natural to say something like,

> Kalya scooted out of bed and made for the toilet

On a side note, I don't see any problem with direct references to the toilet; this isn't the Victorian era.